# No error shows up when a 'required' field is left empty

Tags: visualforce, required-field

I am using  to get as input certain values. I have set the 'required' attribure of inputText to 'true' but unfortunately, if i do not enter any value to the field then no error shows up.

here is what a piece of my code looks like:

```
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
         <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputlabel for="Address_Line1">
            Address Line 1
            </apex:outputlabel>
            <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:inputText id="Address_Line1" value="{!AddrLine1}" required="true"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you want to use required attribute that time you have to add < apex:pageMessage> tag  in your visualforce page if you will add this that time error automatic display when you not fill that field and click submit button.

Comment: I am using inputText and not inputField.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't provided the whole page this is a best guess that you do not have the:

```
<apex:pageMessages/>
```

present in the page which is where the "Validation Error: Value is required." error would be presented.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is inputText and not inputField it doesn't behave the same way. There is a blog on this topic here that walks you through an alternative way of replicating the error:
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/04/field-level-error-messages-with_29.html

Comment: Thanks for help..but I am afraid of using such workarounds as we do not know when the functionality of these styleclass would get changed!!

Comment: You could use <style></style> to create your own but still use the error wrapper method.